# How to provide date with specific format in folder path in Python

Tags: python, filenames, python-3.9, sysdate

I received csv file with sysdate attached to the filename with format `yyyy-mm-dd`. For example today i received file as `User_test_2023-10-20.csv`.

I have below python code where i want to attach this sysdate with format `yyyy-md-dd` to the filename but not sure how to do this.

```
import codecs
import shutil

with codecs.open(r"C:\User_test_.csv", encoding="utf-16") as input_file:
    with codecs.open(r"C:\User_test_.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as output_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(input_file, output_file)
```

Comment: Do you mean that you are trying to access the file based on the current date in sysdate?

Comment: yes it should be sysdate with format yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pathlib
from datetime import datetime

current_date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

path = pathlib.Path(f'C:/User_test_{current_date}.csv')
print(path)
```

Output:

`C:/User_test_2023-10-20.cs`

I will add though:

```
with codecs.open(path, encoding="utf-16") as input_file:
    with codecs.open(path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as output_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(input_file, output_file)
```

Since it seems you want to change the encoding:

```
with path.open("r", encoding="utf-16") as in_file:
    content = in_file.read()
    with path .open("w", encoding="utf-8") as out_file:
        out_file.write(content)
```

Which I'm not sure if it'll work, you whould use different filenames or close one file before overwriting it:

```
import pathlib
from datetime import datetime

current_date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

path = pathlib.Path(f'C:/User_test_{current_date}.csv')

with path.open("r", encoding="utf-16") as in_file:
    content = in_file.read()

with path.open("w", encoding="utf-8") as out_file:
    out_file.write(content)
```

Note: If you didn't need to change encoding you could use `.seek(0)` and `.truncate()` to read and write in a single opening of the file.

Comment: Starting to use pathlib early in learning Python is good because it promotes code readability, safety, platform independence, and future-proofing, making it easier to work with file paths and directories in a consistent and efficient way.

Comment: can you pleas tell me how to adapt this change in my existing code logic because i am getting syntax issue

Comment: Yeah, but not all code should be as short as possible. If that extra code allows him to understand that he can change the format if needed instead of being restricted by `YYYY-MM-DD` that is the default of `str(date.today())` then that's for the best.

Answer (score 1):

We can use datetime module to get the date in this exact format and then just concatenate the strings, this can be done with an f raw string to simplify both the joining and the backslashes of the filename.

```py
from datetime import date
today = str(date.today())
filename = fr'C:\User_test_{today}.csv'
```

Comment: what about format yyyy-mm-dd? and can you pleas tell me how to adapt this change in my existing code logic because i am getting syntax issue

Comment: test it, this specific function returns that exact format

Comment: Also, you are opening the same file twice which sounds problematic, any reason why you don't have a specific output file? This will help me understand better. The way to do now is ```with codecs.open(filename, encoding="utf-16")```

Comment: i want to create that outputfile actually after converting from utf-16 to utf-8..or i want to convert the existing file

Comment: Can you tell me what the error message is after changing?

Comment: AttributeError: module 'shutil' has no attribute 'copyfiUTF16_to_UTF8'

Comment: with codecs.open(
        filename, encoding="utf-16") as input_file:

Comment: You should open and close separatly for that, Daviid just updated his answer for this so you can change the filename like I did and follow what he said which i agree about the encoding part

Comment: No problem, good luck!